# including child expression tree with call to Enumerable.Select

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I would like to use one lambda expression as the argument to the Enumerable.Select method, and add this as a new binding to a parent lambda expression as demonstrated:

```
Expression<Func<Bar, BarDto>> MapBar = b => new BarDto { BarInt = b.BarInt };
Expression<Func<Foo, FooDto>> MapFoo = f => new FooDto { FooInt = f.FooInt };

Expression<Func<Foo, FooDto>> expressionIWant = f => new FooDto
{
    FooInt = f.FooInt,
    Bars = f.Bars.Select(b => new BarDto { BarInt = b.BarInt })
};
```

where I have got to so far:

i have an ExpressionVisitor containing:

```
protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
{
    var newBindings = new[]
    {
        Expression.Bind(_pi, _newExpr),
    };
    node = node.Update(
        node.NewExpression,
        node.Bindings.Concat(newBindings));

    return node;
}
```

I obviously need to include something along the lines of

```
var typeArgs = _originalChildExpression.Type.GenericTypeArguments;
_newExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),"Select",typeArgs,???source???,
    _originalChildExpression);
```

where ???source??? represents the `f.Bars` in the `expressionIWant` at the top. How can this be achieved? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very similar to your previous question. Looking at

```
Expression<Func<Foo, FooDto>> expressionIWant = f => new FooDto
{
    FooInt = f.FooInt,
    Bars = f.Bars.Select(b => new BarDto { BarInt = b.BarInt })
};
```

you can see that `f.Bars` is a `Property("Bars")` of the `Parameter("f")`.

Hence the whole method could be something like this:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, TMap>> AddCollectionMap<T, TMap, U, UMap>(
        this Expression<Func<T, TMap>> parent,
        Expression<Func<U, UMap>> nav, 
        string propName)
    {
        var parameter = parent.Parameters[0];
        var target = typeof(TMap).GetProperty(propName);
        var source = Expression.Property(parameter, propName);
        var binding = Expression.Bind(target, Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "Select", nav.Type.GenericTypeArguments, source, nav));
        var body = parent.Body.AddMemberInitBindings(binding);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TMap>>(body, parameter);
    }

    static Expression AddMemberInitBindings(this Expression expression, params MemberBinding[] bindings)
    {
        return new AddMemberInitBindingsVisitor { Bindings = bindings }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class AddMemberInitBindingsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public MemberBinding[] Bindings;
        protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
        {
            return node.Update(node.NewExpression, node.Bindings.Concat(Bindings));
        }
    }
```

}

and the sample usage:

```
var expressionIGet = MapFoo.AddCollectionMap(MapBar, "Bars");
```